# Flutter Tests: Waiting for a certain duration

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to wait for some time after I tested tapping my button to then check the result with `expect`. I'm using `Future.delayed` for that. But that doesn't work for me. I'm getting a time out error.

```
  TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Test timed out after 5 seconds.
```

This is the code I use:

```
... // other tests
await tester.tap(find.widgetWithText(GestureDetector, "ref size"));
await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 50));
expect(testContainerState.childWidth, 50.0);
```

Does any one have an idea why this (imo) strange behavior occurs?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So, to start out with a simpler answer the correct way to wait for a period of time in a flutter test is using `tester.pump`.

```
await tester.pump(new Duration(milliseconds: 50));
```

The longer answer to why this happens has to do with the flutter testing environment.  To make sure tests are reliable, even in the face of time-varying animations the environment mocks as much of the async behavior as possible, using utilities such as [FakeAsync](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/2.1.0/quiver.testing.async/FakeAsync-class.html) from `package:quiver`.

Comment: in my case this freeze the current screen (into screen at the app start) ... but i need a way to wait until die into screen has been removed and the app home screen have arrived....    so how can i wait for e.g. 5 sec without freezing the app?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to waiting data for Ex can you use this code :

```
 await tester.runAsync(() async {

  // test code here

});
```

**tester** is instance of WidgetTester